# Why am I getting an error in kafka producer when I run it?

Tags: python, twitter, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Hello I am trying to run this code to extract real time tweets with kafka, but is shows **Error received in kafka producer** when I run it. I can't figure out where the problem is.

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import tweepy
import configparser

class TweeterStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()
        self.producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

    def on_status(self, status):
        # This method is called whenever new data arrives from live stream.
        # We asynchronously push this data to kafka queue
        msg =  status.text.encode('utf-8')
        try:
            self.producer.send_messages(b'twitterstream', msg)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False
        return True

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print("Error received in kafka producer")
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        return True # Don't kill the stream
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should somehow access and print the actual error during `on_error`

Comment: You should also be handling rate limiting http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html#handling-errors